# Defining field identity element $0 \in \mathbb{F}$ as an identity polynomial $z \in \mathbb{F}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am currently working on a problem to show that the additive identity element of an abstract field, $0 \in \mathbb{F}$, is the additive identity element in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, the *set of all polynomials with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{F}$*. We define a polynomial as a formal sum:

> $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x^1 + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_k x^k$

I'm mainly confused by how to define the additive identity element as a polynomial, which would then change my proof. The $2$ ways I've been mulling over are as follows:

1. Define $0 \in \mathbb{F}$ as a polynomial by $z \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ with $z = z_0 = 0$. Where then my proof would be something like:

   - $f + z = [\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k] + z_0 = [a_0 + a_1 x^1 + \cdots + a_n x^n] + z_0 = [(a_0 + z_0) + a_1 x^1 + \cdots + a_n x^n] = [(a_0 + 0) + a_1 x^1 + \cdots + a_n x^n] = [a_0 + a_1 x^1 + \cdots + a_n x^n] = f$
2. Define $0 \in \mathbb{F}$ as a polynomial by $z \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ with $z = \sum_{k=0}^{n} z_k x^k$ where $z_k = 0, \forall k \in [0,n]$. Which would alter my proof slightly:

   - $f + z = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n} z_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (a_k + z_k) x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (a_k + 0) x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k = f$

---

Now I know that these definitions are functionally equivalent but I am wondering if there's one that I should go with considering: My text defines constant polynomials as $f = a_0$ hence $z = z_0 = 0$. However when giving the definition of addition of polynomials they make note to reference the fact that the polynomials are constructed in such a way to allow us to add zero coefficients wherever necessary, which makes me think that when adding polynomials they *should* have the same number of terms, with the zero coefficients filling in for any missing power of $x$ terms. Obviously, based on my experience in middle school algebra, I know you can add polynomials that don't have the same number of terms but I'm relatively new to proof-writing and am not very confident in writing these things out abstractly.

Which would you go with? Does it even matter? Again, I know these are functionally equivalent and I'm likely making a much bigger deal out of this than needs to be made but I want to make sure my proof is as accurate as possible. Thanks!

Comment: You can view a polynomial as  $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x^1 + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n + \cdots= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$. This is just a formality; if you have $N$ terms, each of degree $d(j)$, then $\max(d(1),\dots,d(N))$ is an upper bound for the degree of the sum $f(x)+g(x)+\dots +r(x)$

Comment: as @311411 suggest it's easier to invert the polynomial to ensure everything lines up. As an abelian group the terms add component-wise so you can think of each monomial as an index for that coefficient but the labeling is otherwise arbitrary. All their interesting properties come from the multiplication.